# Creating multiple collections from a very large collection and using those smaller collections for every transaction

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

In MongoDB, we have one large collection, which has every possible bit of information we use and it is being updated on a daily basis from different sources. 
Now my question is: Is it a good idea to have multiple collections created from the original collection and to use these collection for the transaction from UI. These small collections are kept updated on daily basis using CRON.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. What do you hope to gain from this?

Comment: Thanks, I am assuming that creating more collections for the similar data have side effect on server. i.e. For each aggregation function there would be a collection. So that Sorting & Searching would be faster rather than calling each time aggregation on mongo original collecton.

Comment: Did you try to solve your performance problems through indexing?

Comment: I think you need to provide more information for anyone to be able to give a coherent answer.